# I'm not able to display those images which were not present when i was "cleaning and building" project in netbeans

Tags: java, image, swing, netbeans

**CONTEXT FOR MY PROBLEM**
I am creating a Project using java swings on netbeans IDE 7.1.2 plateform on 
windows m/c.Then I'm executing the jar file created on windows m/c in a linux m/c(cent os).
In a part of my project i needed to display some pictures in run time.

**PROBLEM STATEMENT**

**Case 1)**
Now what happened is that in run time i brought those pictures from some other location to src directory of my project by executing cp(copy) command through java code.
And yes i have checked those pictures were copied inside src directory successfully.
After that when i tried to display those images in a label,pictures were not being displayed.

So i wondered why is that happening.

**Case 2)**
After this problem i made a change and i imported those pictures inside src folder of my project before "cleaning and building" the project on windows m/c instead of bringing them in run time on linux m/c.Then after this when i executed the jar file on linux m/c,pictures were getting displayed in label.

So only change i made was that i included the pictures in src directory during "cleaning and building" my project on windows m/c.
So what i don't understand is that
why pictures are not getting displayed in 1st case.

**MY QUESTIONS AND DOUBT**
1)  In context to resources like files and pictures(which are being used in project and i'm not talking about source codes of project here),what exactly happens when a jar file is created ? Are those resources(files & pictures) also included in jar while building the project or not?

2) Why i'm facing such a problem ?(And i have also checked the permissions on those image files.They were exactly same in both cases.)

Any insights that any of you can provide will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So I assume you ar doing some thing like

```
label.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/path/to/image"));
```

or

```
BufferdImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("src/path/to/image"));
```

or worse, using absolute file references...

Netbeans will add the content of of your src directory to the resulting jar file when the project is built (excluding your source files ;)), this changes the way in which these resources need to be treated, you can no longer treat them as you would if they were files on the file system.

Once embedded within your application context (such as been included in your jar file), they become what is commonly known as embedded resources.

Instead, you need to use Class#getResource or Class#getResourceAsStream depending on your needs, for example...

```
label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("path/to/image")));
```

**Updated with after more details**

```
Image im=newImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/home/aman/Desktop/diya.jpg")).getImage();
```

Is the wrong approach for his type of file.  This file is a file on the file system, instead you should be using something more like...

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("/home/aman/Desktop/diya.jpg"));
jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
```

Note, `ImageIO.read` throws an `IOException`, which will be expected to catch, this is useful for diagnosing missing files or bad image formats

Unless you have previously changed the visibility state of the label, there is no need to call `setVisible`, in fact, you're setting label invisible anyway...

Comment: I couldn't paste my answer content in comment.So i have added my own answer.Please see to it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment...now i have used-- BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("/home/aman/Desktop/diya.jpg"));
jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image)); and it worked fine.